# Meteor's Template API with React

Tags: meteor

I am currently learning Meteor using React. I saw some usage of Tracker.autorun(), and I read that it was common to use it with Templates. Do these Templates even apply to React or are they for Blaze or even something else? I've never seen a React guide use them. Do people even use Tracker.autorun() with React?

Comment: Not quite an answer to your question, but besides 'Tracker.autorun()', like @mostafiz mentioned, there are some packages which make your React components reactive with Meteor. The Most famous and very easy to use one is [https://github.com/ultimatejs/tracker-react](https://github.com/ultimatejs/tracker-react)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Tracker.autorun` belongs to Meteor's reactive dependency tracking, irrespective of the rendering system like Blaze or React. It allows you a function to be called automatically whenever it's dependent reactive data source changes.

Simply speaking, `Tracker.autorun()`  takes a function as input, runs this function now and returns whenever the data source changes later on.

A simple example how to use `Tracker.autorun()` in React: you can use `Tracker.autorun()` for tracking the user document, since `Meteor.user()` and `Meteor.userId()` are reactive. In `componentDidMount()` call `Tracker.autorun()` and save the user document in elsewhere when it changes.

Hope following code snippet helps:

```
componentDidMount() {
    Tracker.autorun(()=>{
        let user = Meteor.user();
        if (user != undefined) {
                this.setState({ user: user });
        }
    });
}
```